# Open a SlidingDrawer via button

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

How can I open a SlidingDrawer using a button not attached to it?  In other words, I like to open it w/o the handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `open()` on the `SlidingDrawer`.

Comment: what do you mean by open() means where to apply on sliding drawer. Can you please explain

Comment: @Nikki: `SlidingDrawer` is what we refer to in Java as a "class". You have an "instance" of this "class" that is your actual drawer. The "class" has a "method" that is named `open()`. You can call `open()` on the "instance" to open the drawer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to know by sliding drawer, on which button it has to open

Answer (score 5):

Calling `.open()` and `.close()` makes the drawer appear and disappear without animation. I don't know if this is generally the case - I tested this on 4.03 with the drawer in a `RelativeLayout` and it just popped into view without animation.

To make the `SlidingDrawer` open and close by *sliding* into the View when clicking a button, use:

```
slidingDrawer.animateOpen();
```

and

```
slidingDrawer.animateClose();
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you still need help or not but I was just wondering the same thing.

"SlidingDrawer" is our object called "slider":

```
SlidingDrawer slider = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
```

Call the method "open()", using our object name:

```
slider.open();
```

Example button that just opens the sliding drawer:

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        slider.open();
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the handle's touch method(s) and pass down the touch event to the button.